# Session error. The type of the Realm file was invalid

Tags: realm, realm-object-server

I'm trying to use Realm Object Server, but can't access to data.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7B8V.png)

Can you say why I getting this error?

Platform - Android.
Language - Kotlin.
Realm version - 5.4.0

Comment: Please add all relevant code to the question and not as a link to a screenshot. You are much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just used "fullSynchronization" function on builder.

```
private val configuration = SyncUser
        .current()
        .createConfiguration(OutdoorAllyConstants.REALM_OA_REGS_URL)
        .waitForInitialRemoteData()
        .fullSynchronization()
        .build()
```